# Python, find parallel Left Right Linestrings from all Lines

Tags: python, gdal, geopandas, shapely

I have thousands of lines and I am trying to identify the closest parallel line on each side of the lines within a distance.

Using Python, my idea was to draw a buffer from each line on one side and check if there are any intersects, then if there are, find the closest one with a similar azimuth (maybe within 10 degrees), then do the same for the opposite side.

```
pos_df = gdf.copy()
neg_df = gdf.copy()

pos_df['geometry'] = pos_df.to_crs('EPSG:32040').buffer(50000, single_sided=True)
neg_df['geometry'] = neg_df.to_crs('EPSG:32040').buffer(-50000, single_sided=True)
```

in the image below, line D would fall within line B's distance, so there would be a column called right, and line D would be placed in here for line B, if that makes sense.

Would anyone know the a way to accomplish this task using Python? I've been stumped on how to do this.

[image]